# Can Zenos paradox of motion be applied to a flashing blue light?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, metaphysics, philosophy-of-physics, paradox

Zenos paradoxes of motion generally refer to actual motion through space; however for Aristotle this is motion in only one sense; an other sense could be alteration, for example change in shape and so on.

Consider a motionless particle painted blue and which slowly changes in colour intensity and then back down again - in effect a slowly flashing blue dot.

Does Zenos paradox of motion apply to this situation?

Of course, were we to model this mathematically ie via coordinates, with one axis for time and the other for colour intensity then Zenos paradoxes apply; and the standard solution suffices to the extent it does.

But I want this question to be thought through physically - can it 
be?

---

Arjuna slay thy doubts and slay thy fears:

Cast your clouds upon the sea;

And then your storms upon the lands.

Comment: I don't know about your flashing blue dot, but apparently the ancient Greek philosophers -- don't know about the engineers -- had no notion of measuring the speed of an object. This led to the silliness that is Zeno's Paradox. Galileo, several centuries later, essentially dispensed with it with his simple speed-distance-time formula. I'm not sure why it is still an issue for some today.

Comment: Well it takes an accurate clock to measure time; given the Greeks adoption of geometry we can safely say they knew how to measure distances; it wouldn't surprise me they couldn't measure speed due to not having a good clock; still just because one can't measure something accurately doesn't mean that one can't have a notion of it; for example Aristotle discusses the speed of a falling object as being proportional to weight and inversely proportional to the density of the surrounding medium; though this is wrong - it does show that they had the notion of speed.

Comment: Galileos conception doesn't solve Zenos paradoxes; for example it's generally accepted that it's the notion of infinite sums that solve that particular problem; plus there are problems to do with continua vs discrete structure.

Comment: @christensen: see [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/178788/when-and-who-by-was-the-earliest-definition-of-speed?noredirect=1#comment379071_178788) where it's pointed out that speed was defined by Aristotle in his *Physics*, book VII, part 5.

Comment: @DanChristensen   Metaphysics is not science.  The notion of infinitely differentiable speed is still logically flawed in a metaphysical sense.  Observation of the provably impossible is not an argument.  The actual impossible thing needs to be found and rejected.  What is impossible here is the infinite division of the motion of an object along a smooth curve.  This was not resolved by Galileo, or even by Newton, but by the atomists' notion of vibration, and ultimately by Heisenberg.  And it is still hard for most folks to believe.

Comment: @jobermark: are you talking about the *clinamen*?

Comment: Its modern equivalent post-Boltzmann or deBroglie.  Brownian motion or quantum vibration does not allow for infinite subdivision of Achilles path.  If he did not make any progress at all, his center of mass would still jerk around uncontrollably at some level of subdivision of space.  Basically, the modern atomists had to take a page from Heraclitus, and admit that rest is impossible, so motion is inevitable.  Elea put physics on a given path that it stayed on for a very long time, but rest, not motion, it is an illusion.

Comment: I'd say it makes no difference whether we think of this issue 'physically' or theoretically or as a problem of motion or flashing lights. The problem still remains. Some say the calculus solves it but there is plenty of opposition to this idea within mathematics and more elsewhere. Buddhist philosophers regularly argue against the possibility of naively-real change and motion so you could check them out.   . .

Comment: @jobermark: It depends on quite what you mean by rest. It's given by Aristotle and then Newton that rest is that state in where no external forces act. This characterisation definitely allows motion as Newton showed.

Comment: @MoziburUllah  And quantum mechanics shows that Newton's approach would fail here.  The intensity cannot vary continuously nor could the intensity stay exactly the same over any measurable length of time.  The idea of the derivative and inertia does not apply here.   Space and time may still be continuous, but energy intensity simply is not.  So it is not a solution to this modified problem.  Heisenberg's principle and the wave equation disown that definition of rest, because in a quantum world, what forces, or even what particles are 'outside' are not adequately well-defined.

Comment: @jobermark: The evolution of the wave function is actually continuous... it's collapse that is discontinuous. Besides, what I'm talking about here is the notion of change in a situation where motion as in change of place doesn't apply which is the situation where Zeno asked his question.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Not the point.  It still makes defining what is 'internal' vs what is 'external' impossible.  So it dissolves the definition you gave of rest.  This is a nonresponse.  And what you are talking about is one version of the question, but it is not 'physical', given that physics has changed since Newton.  That is what he asked for.  In some sense the probability of the intensity could increase continuously, but the intensity itself cannot.  Quantum dynamics is atomistic relative to brightness.  And Zeno's argument against the discrete case is bizarre and makes no sense.

Comment: @jobermark: Newton already knew that his physics wasn't complete. He was theorising about inter-atomic forces well before people even knew about them - so I think he was further ahead in the game than people give him credit for. The point of my question is asking Zenos question about change in alteration and not motion.

Comment: OK, well you answered that yourself in the question.  Two continuous things will still have Zeno's paradox.  Then why bring 'physically' into it?  Ask some question that means something.  If the alteration is continuous (which is impossible) then the coordinates are valid and your argument already settled.

Comment: @jobermark: I didn't answer my own question in the question. I just elaborated what I meant by the question as you appear to be insistent in misunderstanding or mis-characterising it. Alteration is a technical term in Aristotelian physics.

Comment: @MoziburUllah  If by physically, you mean Aristotelian physics only, you should probably say that in the question.  If you include in 'physically' any modern physics, then I am not mischaracterizing the question.  It is ambiguous, and I am answering a version you have not yet actually ruled out.

Comment: @jobermark: I do mention Aristotle in the question ... do you have any other bright suggestions?

Comment: @MoziburUllah It remains ambiguous even so.  So I suppose I don't have any suggestions you might actually take.

Comment: Why single me out instead of responding to 'nir' who made basically the same mischaracterization earlier.

Comment: @jobermark: I'm not intending to single you out - I'm just responding to your comments. If 'nir' comes out of hiding then I will respond to him. But I don't see anything here.

Answer (score 2):

However you generate light, the excited medium always 'warms up' before it can emit it and 'cools down' before it stops.  If the variation in the intensity of light is not a collection of short bursts that get spaced out further to give the illusion of dimming, it is driven by a current or heat which would have to vary continuously.

So in each case there is still a continuous process involved, unless you think of these effects at a quantum level.  Whatever varies continuously is subject to Zeno's paradox.

At a quantum level, Zeno's paradox does not apply, because there is no absolute rest, and so the attempt to declare the particle not to have already moved by the time you establish its position is a complete non-sequitur.  Heraclitus is right, and the Eleatics and all their successors are wrong, on this: The lack of motion is the thing that is essentially alien to all matter.

Answer (score 2):

The answer in this case is no since the intensity of emitted light is the number of photons emitted per unit time, which is not a continuous quantity.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.  There is a middle color between the least color intensity and highest color intensity.  There is a middle color between the middle color and the least color intensity, and so on.  This halving goes on infinitely.  Therefore, a change in color can never be completed.